# How to fill this region with color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have the following very simple graph:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,-1)--(0,1) node[anchor=south east] {};
\draw[thick,->] (-1,0)--(1,0) node[anchor=north west] {};
\draw (-2,-2)--(2,2) node[anchor=north west] {};
\draw (-2,2)--(2,-2) node[anchor=north west] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

This gives two cones on the x-y plane. How can I color these two regions?

Comment: Please, can be more specific? Which two region you like to fill? I don't see any cone ...

Comment: Also please explain, what is purpose of empty nodes?

Comment: A complete compilable document would make it easier for people to help. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Do you mean something like `\fill[red] (-2,-2) -- (0,0) -- (-2,2) -- cycle;` ?

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise, I was in a hurry. The empty nodes are not needed. Also, the answer below is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Thruston says in the comments you can use the `\fill` command together with a closed path to colour a region. You can also use `\draw[fill=<colour>]` and many other tikz commands accept `fill=...` as an argument.

To add text to the picture you can use the `\node` command, which uses the syntax

```
\node at (x,y)[options]{text};
```

Alternatively, and almost equivalently, you can use:

```
\draw[draw options] (x,y) node[node options]{text};
```

For the various options for `\node` and `\draw` see the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual.

It's  not clear which regions you want to colour, so the following code does all of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \ang/\col in {0/red,1/green,2/blue,3/yellow} {
       \fill[\col!20] (45+90*\ang:2.8)--(0,0)--(45+90*\ang+90:2.8)--cycle;
    }
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-1)--(0,1);
    \draw[thick,->] (-1,0)--(1,0);
    \draw (-2,-2)--(2,2);
    \draw (-2,2)--(2,-2);
    \node at (0,1.5)[blue]{Some nice text};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that you want to colour the region first so that the colours are "underneath" the rest of your drawing. For more complicated drawings you might need the tikz `backgrounds` library.

The code above gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. May I kindly ask how to include text, say, in the red region?

Comment: The easiest way to add text is using the `\node` command. I'll add an example.